# Problems adding Visual Studio 2015 project to Source control

Tags: c#, git, version-control, visual-studio-2015

I have a solution with two projects in it. One of them is added to source control, but the other is not. They are in different folder paths (let's say project that is added to source control is in `PATH-TRACKED`, but the other in the `PATH-UNTRACKED`).

What is a correct way to get that untracked project to the git repository folder `PATH-TRACKED` so that I don't brake my solution? By moving to the `PATH_TRACKED` I could add it to source control, but then I would brake the references to that project, right? What is the recommended way to do this task?

**As a result** I want to have both projects in the same repository

Comment: This is not a question with an easy answer. If you have a repository already for one of the projects, what do you really want to do with the other? Add it to the same repository? Create a separate repository for it? Move the project with the repository into a sub-directory of that repository to make room for the untracked on? You need to tell us what you really want to happen here.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen explanation added - I want to add that untracked project to the same project - so as a result I would have one repository for both projects

Comment: Move the untracked folder into your repository and move the other directory in a su folder if needed and all should be go well! Just do it in one commit without introducing other changes. If the commit do not suit you, git reset and do it again... No need to worry.

Comment: @Philippe thanks, I'll give it a try Thursday and then comment it (+you could post an answer, so I could mark it, if it will help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git is quite good at following file because its file detection is based on the content. So, if you don't modify the content of the files in the same time you move your files, their should be no problem.

So, move the untracked folder into your repository and move the other directory in a sub folder, if needed, and all should be go well! Just do it without introducing other changes (especially in the content of the files). Do it in one or two commit if you find it clearer...

Anyway, if the commit you end with do not suit you, `git reset` and do it again (or even better, `amend` it)... No need to worry. Here, git is not the problem but perhaps you will have to update some files (sln or csproj) to make all that build :(